# Initialize long value which was get from other activity

Tags: java, android, sqlite, bundle, long-integer

I get a long value from other activity and want to save it in sqlite.

```
long fk;
fk = bundle.getLong("ab"); // value ab get from other activities
k.insertStaffBenefit(name,result,fk);
```

**StaffAPI.java**

```
public class StaffAPI {
        private SQLiteDatabase database;
        private MyDatabaseHelper dbHelper;
        public String[] allColumns={MyDatabaseHelper.ID3, MyDatabaseHelper.Description,MyDatabaseHelper.Amount,MyDatabaseHelper.Twd_id};

        public StaffAPI(Context context)
        {
            dbHelper=new MyDatabaseHelper(context);
        }

        public void open() throws SQLException {
            database = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        }

        public void close() {
            dbHelper.close();
        }
        public long insertStaffBenefit(String description,String amount,long id)
        {
            database=dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
            ContentValues values=new ContentValues();
            values.put(MyDatabaseHelper.Description,description);
            values.put(MyDatabaseHelper.Amount,amount);
            values.put("Twd_id",id);
            database.insert(MyDatabaseHelper.TABLE_STAFF_BENEFICT,null,values);
            database.close();
            return 0 ;

        }

    }
```

I know I have to  initialize `a` since it might pointing towards null,  but how can  I do to fix this?

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'long
>   com.example.project.project.API.StaffAPI.insertStaffBenefit(java.lang.String,
>   java.lang.String, long)' on a null object reference

Comment: Anyone know how to solve?

Comment: crash occured in your com.example.project.project.API.StaffAPI.insertStaffBenefit,please show this code and invoke code.

Comment: Please show your insertToDB and insertStaffBenefit method.

Comment: edited..`name` and `result` working fine

Comment: the **k** in k.insertStaffBenefit(name,result,fk);  is null,check it and show it here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont think that your error comes from `NullPointerException` of `long`. `long` is primitive data type, and it has default value and you cant assign `null` value to it as: `long a = null`. There's no way. Therefore, I suggest that you check your `bundle.getLong("foreignKey")` before assigning it:

```
long a;
a= bundle.getLong("foreignKey") != null? bundle.getLong("foreignKey") : 0; 
k.insertToDB(a);
```

**Edit:**

From your logcat, error occurs when you trying to invoke `insertStaffBenefit` from `null` object (k in your code). Try to check it.

Comment: I did something like this    `Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), fk+"", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();` and it shows `fk` value

Comment: did you initialize `k` before using `k.insertStaffBenefit(name,result,a);`? The logcat tell us that you tried to invoke `insertStaffBenefit` from a `null` object. That means `k is null` in your code.

Comment: Thanks..I miss out to write  `k= new com.example.project.project.API.StaffAPI(getActivity());`

Answer (score 1):

a is long, not Long, so its default value is 0, not null. Then you can watch the source code  of the method getLong("foreignKey"), [method getLong(String key)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/41Ce7.png)

Its default value is 0, and its return kind is long, not Long. 
So you needn't to judge whether a is null.
The error is not that a is null, but invoke insertStaffBenefit.